# SQL Server 2008 R2 Job Fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Please excuse my ignorance! We had a job running fine on MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (64bit) and on 21st July it suddenly stopped. The error message we get is

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\joe.bloggs. 10:37:23.82
>   Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error 
>   Error: 2013-09-04 10:37:23.91     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data
>   Flow Task 1      Description: There were errors during task
>   validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:37:22  Finished: 10:37:23  Elapsed: 
>   1.796 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Can anyone shed any light on this at all? I can't access integration services due to permissions. I try and open the solution in BIDS but get the message

> One or more projects in the solution could not be loaded for the following reason(s):
>   The project file or web has been removed, renamed or is not on your computer

Even after deleting the SUO file, this still happens.

There's one step in the JOB and when I go to edit it it's set to run as "proxy_jbloggs" not sure if that helps?

I don't know why but I think there may be something up with the joe.bloggs user account but no idea how/why/where/what/when

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new project and add the dtsx file to the project. Also it looks like the SSIS package references an assembly file which is most likely stored on the SSIS server.

Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: remember, this should be a comment ;)